# ./ and ../ directory differences

Tags: html, node.js, filesystems

I know this question will get so many downvotes and will be marked as a duplicate.

The problem is I searched a lot about that question and never got a satisfying answer.

When working with sources in HTML and we want to get an image from the same folder of the HTML file we type the image name directly. If it's inside a folder which is in the same place as the HTML file is, we type the folder name then image, and so on....

If the image is in a folder which contains another folder in which the HTML file exists, so we want to get one step back. We type ../ which means go one step back then the image name.

When I started learning node and how to use modules, modules which were in the same folder as the node file is, must be imported using ./ which was explained as 'in the same folder', while when we import modules like 'fs' and 'events' they don't need a ./

Can someone explain why we don't use ./ in html files while they are used sometimes in node and sometimes no?!

Comment: Did you read this? https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/63081/what-are-and-directories

Comment: @RomeoSierra That's a good article, but it doesn't seem to discuss why `./` would or would not need to be used in certain cases.

Comment: The article doesn't really discuss the issue in the question which is the two last lines of the question.

Comment: That *WHY?* I think is technology dependent. We know that `./` is a *notation* that refers to the current directory. A notation is as good as how it is understood. It's like we teach a child that *"this is letter A"* while we are pointing to a symbol. That symbol may be `A` or it may be `Z`. We have programmed (by we I am referring to everybody who developed modern day browsers) the browsers to look for the resources starting from the current location that the web page it tries to load. To instruct about this *current location* we use nothing at the beginning of the resource location string..

Answer (score 1):

I want to explain it because the node default import setting.

like 'fs' and 'events', these library was installed with node installed, and was included by default. And these will be stored in system directory. Just like `<stdio.h>` for c, `fs` from python. It's the default library for the corresponding language.

But sometimes you write you own libraries wanted to be import by other node file, you should import it by using relative path...Because if you don't write './', it will default search the system file directory where is stored 'fs', 'http' and so on, node will not find your libraries.

Comment: So 'events' doesn't need a ./ because it's built-in? That's for the node part, but what about the HTML part?

Comment: 'events' doesn't need a ./ because it's built-in is right. HTML part means importing it in HTML?

Answer (score 1):

Before we start `./` and `../` notation is used to refer files relatively.

> Why we sometimes don't use `./` in node?

All the modules we install in NodeJS are in the folder `node modules`. Whenever you require a module `require('fs')` or `require('3rdparty')`. Node exactly knows where to look for the module as it is installed as a folder in local node_modules or global node_modules. And then it loads the `index.js` and then so on..

> When to use `./` in node?

`./` is a way(Relative way) to refer files in the file system. If you have a script which is part of the file system and not as part of a node_module, then you use './' or '../' notation based on your file location

> Why we don't use `./` in HTML files?

As said by @sami, you can use either `./` or not. It works in both ways. I am accustomed to `./` when I work. It's more of personal opinion.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Doesn’t have anything to do with Windows or Linux. URLs are absolute or relative and relative is always based on the base URL and doesn’t need any ./